# Determine whether following series converge or diverge. If converges find its sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series

### $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n n^2}{1 + 2 n^2}}$$

here is what I have done.

so when:

- $n=1$ [for this term] it gives = - 1/3 or - 0.3333
- $n=2$ gives 0.4444
- $n=3$ gives -0.2923977
- $n=4$ gives 0.484848

we values are alternating between +ves and -ves is this enough to say series is divergent?

and also as we are progressing some values are actually increasing eg 0.444 to 0.4848 which also gives a hint that it is divergent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The series is divergent because the sequence of its summands is not converging towards $0$ (which is a necessary condition for a series to converge). In fact it does not converge at all. The sequence of summands is given by $(-1)^n\frac{n^2}{2n^2+1}$. The $\frac{n^2}{2n^2+1}$ part converges towards $\frac{1}{2}$ because $\frac{n^2}{2n^2+1}=\frac{\frac{n^2}{n^2}}{2\frac{n^2}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^2}}=\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{n^2}}\to\frac{1}{2}$. Thus the original sequence $(-1)^n\frac{n^2}{2n^2+1}$ has two cluster points that is $\frac{1}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ corresponding to the limits of the subsequences $(-1)^{2n}\frac{(2n)^2}{2(2n)^2+1}=\frac{(2n)^2}{2(2n)^2+1}\to\frac{1}{2}$ and $(-1)^{2n+1}\frac{(2n+1)^2}{2(2n+1)^2+1}=-\frac{(2n+1)^2}{2(2n+1)^2+1}\to-\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2):

The terms of the series don't tend to $0$, so the series cannot converge.